# How to use Loki's Pimpl implementation?

Tags: c++, pimpl-idiom, c++-loki

Link to source code of Loki Pimpl [header](http://loki-lib.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/loki-lib/loki/include/loki/Pimpl.h?view=markup).
I am not able to find any documentation on how to use the same, can any one explain how to use.
And what does the following function in the header do.

1. PimplOwner
2. ImplOf
3. PimplOf
4. RimplOf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](http://209.85.229.132/search?q=cache:JUecI0Ssvp0J:bbteam.fr/mediawiki/index.php/Pimpl+loki+pimpl&cd=7&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=es&lr=lang_en|lang_es) has most of the information you need

Comment: Your search - ... - did not match any documents

Comment: The link is no longer valid.

Comment: I guess I have found the given link via wayback machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20081113013932/http://bbteam.fr/mediawiki/index.php/Pimpl. If I am right, please write down those content here to improve your answer. Then we may not depend on time machines :)

Answer (score 0):

[Loki](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/) has a short smart pointer ([Smart Pointer](http://loki-lib.cvs.sourceforge.net/loki-lib/loki/include/loki/SmartPtr.h?view=markup)). I use [Loki::Pimpl](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/index.php?n=Idioms.Pimpl) and smart pointer defined as follows:

```
Loki::Pimpl<string, ConstPropPtr<string> > smartPoint;
```

you can try to use this.